# Extended class calling function that should not be inherited

Tags: android, inheritance, handler

i have following problem:
I've made a simple android app that adds 1 to an integer every 1000 ms using a handler, and then display this integer.
The problem is that when i start another activity the same thing happens, which would be fine, if that was intended. The mentioned function is not called in the new activity and yet it seems to be. Please look over my code and show me where it went wrong..

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

protected TextView text;
protected int position;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private int i = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    position=0;
    SetButtonCLickListener();
    counter();
}

protected void SetButtonCLickListener() {
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SwitchActivity();
        }
    });
}

private void counter() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(count);
    handler.postDelayed(count, 1000);
}

private Runnable count = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        i++;
        text.setText("Count: " + i);
        handler.postDelayed(count, 1000);

    }
};

protected void SwitchActivity() {
    if (position == 1) {
            finish();

    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
}
```

**SecondActivity**

```
public class MainActivity2 extends MainActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    SetButtonCLickListener();
    position=1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MainActivity2` has an `onCreate()` method. In the `onCreate()` method, you call `super.onCreate()`, which triggers the `MainActivity` implementation of `onCreate()`. The `MainActivity` implementation of `onCreate()` is where you are starting your counter thing, via its call to the `counter()` method. Hence, when `MainActivity2` starts up, its `onCreate()` calls `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()`, which calls `counter()`.

My guess is that `MainActivity2` should inherit from `Activity`, not from `MainActivity`.

Comment: You are right, though i had hoped it would be possible this way.